# Why is my JUNIT 5 not working Im trying to create a tester but I get "cannot resolve symbol `Assertions`? I Did it in root source code and then fix

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, junit5, intellij-14

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON544.png) I don't know if Im supposed to put the jar file somewhere in my path or if I can place it anywhere currently Its not directly on my path maybe thats why its not working I would like to know how to fix.

I want to be able to make a simple tester but I can't.

Comment: You'll want to make sure that junit-jupiter-api is in your class path.  Have a look under `File > Project Structure` for `Project Settings > Libraries`.  Add the jar there if it's not already listed.

Comment: You could check the documentation here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#define-a-project-library to know how to add the library to the project.